# Cannot transfer files to Windows Server 2012 IIS with FTPS encryption active

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012, ftp, ftps, winscp

So I'm pretty new to IIS and FTPS, tho I usually use ubuntu and vsftpd with sftp for secure file transfer.
But in this case I was tasked with setting up a FTP server on a Windows server 2012 environment.
Set up the user and FTP service and did a test transfer with WinSCP and FileZilla, so far so good.

But since some sensitive data will be transferred we needed encryption so I created a self signed certificate and set it to force encryption in SSL settings.

I tested the setup again and was able to log in. I could create directories and move files around.
But when I tried to transfer files the transfer fails when the upload was finished with the message:

```
Using TLSv1.2, cipher TLSv1/SSLv3: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384, 2048 bit RSA, ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384 Copying files to remote side failed.
```

Looking in the logfile I could see one entry with the filename of the file I tested a transfer on:

```
STOR aircontrol-v2.0-beta20.1631.160317.1513-win64.exe 550 2148074264 0 202 73855447 4570 1d3abd73-5c55-48c8-a3b5-63b6ca868863 /aircontrol-v2.0-beta20.1631.160317.1513-win64.exe -
```

And that's all to it.
I tried to do the same with FileZilla and got the same results.

Is there anyone who has an idea what to do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you transferring the files locally or is a firewall or internet connection involved?

Comment: It's over the internet. I've checked the firewall and opened ports for passive FTPS connections with no result

Answer (score 0):

Try to vary TLS version settings:
https://forums.iis.net/t/1163993.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you are using DFS (file replication) in the destination directory, that will give you TLS problems.
Just erase DFS replication (not try to stop service, it will not work)